# How can I filter a csv file based on its columns in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, spyder

I have a CSV file with over 5,000,000 rows of data that looks like this (except that it is in Farsi):

```
Contract Code,Contract Type,State,City,Property Type,Region,Usage Type,Area,Percentage,Price,Price per m2,Age,Frame Type,Contract Date,Postal Code
765720,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,96,100,570000,5937.5,36,Metal,13890107,5169614658
766134,Mobayee,East Azar,Qeshm,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1070000,7404.84,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766140,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1050000,7266.44,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766146,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,700000,4844.29,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766147,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1625000,11245.67,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
770822,Mobayee,East Azar,Tabriz,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,50,500000,1730.1,5,Concrete,13890114,5166884645
```

I would like to write a code to pass the first row as the header and then extract data from two specific cities (Kish and Qeshm) and save it into a new CSV file. Somthing like this one:

```
Contract Code,Contract Type,State,City,Property Type,Region,Usage Type,Area,Percentage,Price,Price per m2,Age,Frame Type,Contract Date,Postal Code
765720,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,96,100,570000,5937.5,36,Metal,13890107,5169614658
766134,Mobayee,East Azar,Qeshm,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1070000,7404.84,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
766147,Mobayee,East Azar,Kish,Apartment,,Residential,144.5,100,1625000,11245.67,5,Concrete,13890108,5166884645
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm very new to python.
I've written the following block to define the headers, but this is the furthest I've gotten so far.

```
import pandas as pd

path = '/Users/Desktop/sample.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path , header=[0])
df.head = ()
```

Comment: Check if the city [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) the desired list, then save [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), i.e.: `df[df.City.isin(['Kish', 'Qeshm'])].to_csv('out.csv', index=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `header=...` because the default is to treat the first row as the header, so

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Then, to keep rows on conditions:

```
df2 = df[df['City'].isin(['Kish', 'Qeshm'])]
```

And you can save it with

```
df2.to_csv(another_path)
```